# Roles required to allow user to manage storage account keys, containers, blobs on the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, rbac

I need to allow Azure AD user to manage - via the Azure Portal - containers, blobs, keys for a given storage account.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#assign-the-reader-role-for-portal-access) state that the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role by itself **will not** provide sufficient permissions to navigate through the portal to the blob in order to view it. So to enable user **to navigate** through the Portal - the **Reader** role is required.

Am I right that I need to assign **Reader**, **Storage Account Contributor** and **Storage Blob Data Contributor** roles to achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you have access to the account in question to log in as them and try,  or have them try and iterate

Comment: @PatrickGoode I can't do this in our effective subscription, I just do not have rights. I'm making a requirement for our admins. I've already given them a draft. So now I can play with my own Azure AD to check everything.

Comment: I think I understand, do you still need help on this?

Comment: @PatrickGoode I'll make an update if I stumble at something I can't solve. In a few days they're gonna create the storage account + configs, and I guess this won't be set in stone, so there will be a chance to figure out what roles we really need. Patrick, I really apreciate your attention!